# Making f:selectItem width same to its p:selectOneMenu and wrap f:selectItem

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to achieve these things with my `selectOneMenu`:

- Make the `f:selectItem`'s width to adapt the size of its `p:selectOneMenu`
- Wrap the `f:selectItem`'s text if the `itemLabel` is too long
- Hide the remaining text inside `p:selectOneMenu` and not overlap

I tried several solutions but I have had no luck. I hope you guys can help me.

Here is my HTML:

```
<p:panelGrid class="input-form" columns="2" layout="grid" style="width: 100%;">
<h:outputLabel styleClass="input-label hidden-sm" value="Register by :" style="font-weight:bold" />
<p:selectOneMenu style="width:100%;">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Savings Account Number" itemValue="Savings Account Number"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Mobile Number Registered in XYZ" itemValue="Mobile Number Registered in XYZ"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Special Card" itemValue="Special Card"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Employer / Household Employer ID Number" itemValue="Employer / Household Employer ID Number"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Payment Reference / XYZ / Payment Receipt Transaction Number" itemValue="Payment Reference / XYZ / Payment Receipt Transaction Number"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
body .ui-selectonemenu {
overflow:auto; 
white-space:pre; 
text-overflow:ellipsis;
-webkit-appearance: none;
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
-moz-transition: border-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
-o-transition: border-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
transition: border-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s; }
body .ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-label {
color: #212529;
box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none; }
```

I am using **Primefaces Avalon Theme**.

Images for reference:

[image: sample of my f:selectItem]

[image: Overlapping text]

Comment: The list of items is in a separate div with class ui-selectonemenu-panel. This panel has inline styles for width, top, left. I think, you don't can style this box.

Comment: Hello @Holger. When I inspected the element, the classes of the selectItem are as follows: ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow ui-input-overlay. Is it really impossible for selelectItem to adapt the width of selectOneMenu?

Comment: Normally the width is adapted. SelectOneMenu grows with the used selectItems. But if SelectOneMenu can't grow any more, because of an outer box, the panel can grow. As you can see, the ui-selectonemenu-panel is at the bottom of the document. Outside any table or panel.