# In jsf, how to wrap the text in select option(SelectOneMenu)

Tags: jsf

In SelectOneMenu, one of the value is overflowing in drop-down and that value should be aligned according with other value.

Comment: would you please add more details to your question and share what you have tried?

Comment: Same way as in plain html because that is what jsf generates.

Comment: I find this similar post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50478668/making-fselectitem-width-same-to-its-pselectonemenu-and-wrap-fselectitem)

Comment: Can anyone provide solution for this..

Comment: The link you refer to is for PrimeFaces, your question is about **plain jsf**. Plain jsf renders plain html (do a view-source on the client). And so your solution is identical you that for plain html. Effectively not jsf related. Post the plain html tag the question with html and remove the jsf tag and you will hopefully get answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Dropdown (select) with Text Wrap and Border after every value (option)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578388/html-dropdown-select-with-text-wrap-and-border-after-every-value-option)

Answer (score -1):

Following skinning styles are available for selectOneMenu

- .ui-selectonemenu Main container.
- .ui-selectonemenu-label Label of the component.
- .ui-selectonemenu-trigger Container of dropdown icon.
- .ui-selectonemenu-items Items list.
- .ui-selectonemenu-items Each item in the list.

try the following for your menu

`.ui-selectonemenu-items {
    display: inline !important;
}`

or you can use

`word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: Which **pure** jsf compoment is this for?